# What does this means in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I come across these codes while exploring flutter as a beginner

**FIRST CODE**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Helo world',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.cyan),
      home: HomePage(),
      routes: {
        "/fullPage": buildFullPage,
        "/form": buildFormPage,
        "/view": buildViewPage,
      },
    );
  }
```

**SECOND CODE**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'GridView Demo',
      home: SplashScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        accentColor: Color(0xFF761322),
      ),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        SPLASH_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => SplashScreen(),
        HOME_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(),
        //GRID_ITEM_DETAILS_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => GridItemDetails(),
      },
    ));
```

I NEED YOUR HELP IN KNOWING THESE MULTIPLE ROUTING

What these mean in FIRST CODE

```
home: HomePage(),
      routes: {
        "/fullPage": buildFullPage,
        "/form": buildFormPage,
        "/view": buildViewPage,
      },
```

What these mean in SECOND CODE

```
home: SplashScreen(),
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        SPLASH_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => SplashScreen(),
        HOME_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(),
        //GRID_ITEM_DETAILS_SCREEN: (BuildContext context) => GridItemDetails(),
      },
```

Comment: Creating constants always helps you since you may misspell something. Its recommended to use constants ("Second Code") over magic strings like one in the "First Code".

Comment: it means SECOND CODE  is better than FIRSTCODE